# window.location.replace Login Form Issue (html, javascript)

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make a simple login form with html and javascript, but whenever I use window.location.replace to change to the next page, it never works. It works if I get the password wrong, but all it does if I get it right is submit the form to the url (url.com/?pswrd=password). I don't want to use SQL or any type of password protection for this project.

```
        <form onsubmit="checkForm(this)">
        <input id="password"
         type="password"
         name="pswrd"/>

        <input id="btn" onclick="checkForm(this.form)" type="submit" value="Login" class="hvr-float-shadow"/>
    </form>
    </font>
    <script>
        function checkForm(form) {
             if(form.pswrd.value == "[censored]") {
                window.location.replace('/indexproxy.php')
            }
             else if(form.pswrd.value == "[censored]") {
                window.location.replace('/indexproxy.php')
            }
             else if(form.pswrd.value == "[censored]") {
                window.location.replace('/indexproxy.php')
            }
             else if(form.pswrd.value == "[censored]") {
                window.location.replace('/indexproxy.php')
            }
             else if(form.pswrd.value == "[censored]") {
                window.location.replace('/indexproxy.php')
            }
             else if(form.pswrd.value == "[censored]") {
                window.location.replace('/indexproxy.php')
            }
            else {
                alert("Incorrect access code, please try again.");
            }
 };
    </script>
<font face=arial color=white size=2>
<p>All access codes are CaSe SeNsiTIVE</p>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can do something like that

chage form tag from this

```html
<form onsubmit="checkForm(this)">
```

to this

```html
<form onsubmit="return checkForm(this)" method="post" action="indexproxy.php">
```

and the this is the function

```js
function checkForm(form) {
       if(form.pswrd.value == "[censored]") {
          return true;
      }
      else if(form.pswrd.value == "[censored]") {
          return true;
      }
      else if(form.pswrd.value == "[censored]") {
          return true;
      }
      else if(form.pswrd.value == "[censored]") {
          return true;
      }
      return false;
 };
```

So if your password is correct, the form will send you to the indexproxy.php page, otherwise it will stop

Answer (score 3):

The form is submitting because **you are clicking a submit button in a form**.

Use `type="button"` instead.

Better yet, move your logic server side where people can't find out your passwords by viewing the source.

Comment: But I also want the functionality to press enter to check the form.